# PrimeNG File Upload does nothing when an XML File is selected

Tags: xml, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a basic PrimeNG File Upload and when I select a XML File nothing happens.
 Normaly when I select a PNG or TXT File a success or error message appears (checked with PDF as well - not working).

Here is my HTML:

```
<p-fileUpload mode="basic" name="files[]" url="./importTotpHardwareTokens" accept="text/xml" maxFileSize="100000" (onUpload)="onFileUpload($event)" (onError)="onFileError($event)" auto="true" chooseLabel="Import">
</p-fileUpload>
```

I changed `accept="text/xml"` to `accept=""`, which allows every type of files and it's not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `accept="text/xml"` with `[accept]="text/xml"`

This one fails :

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php" accept="text/xml" auto="true" chooseLabel="Import"></p-fileUpload>
```

but not this one :

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php" [accept]="text/xml" auto="true" chooseLabel="Import"></p-fileUpload>
```

Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uAjgbSB8MUAft6qsOGyz?p=preview)

Comment: That's not working for me. I'm still able to upload txt or png files but it's still not doing anything for xml files.

Comment: @Anaa I added a plunker.